# Find when month appears five times in JavaScript loop (date, string)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date, for-loop

I am building a paycheck month calculator. If you normally get paid every other week, most months will have two paychecks but two months of each year will have three paychecks.

My program works as expected, it appends to a list the date of everyday starting today (today being a Friday). Now I would like to make list items with the same month that appears five times stand out, simple coloring would work.

Can this be done with a second function `for li in ul` and then `if li[i] string[4][6] === the next li[i][4][6]` and then somehow search for five? I'm not sure how the logic would work. The reason why I picked [4][6] is because in each list item, the months are all three letter abbreviations that occupy the same part of the string.

How can this be done?

```js
var d;
var week = 7;

function getDates() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + week);
    $('#date').append("<li>" + d + "</li>");
    week += 7;
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getDates();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="date"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty example:

```js
var d;
var week = 7;

function getDates() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + week);
    $('#date').append("<li data-mth='"+d.getMonth()+"'>" + d + "</li>");
    week += 7;
  }
  $('li[data-mth]').each(function(){
    var $group = $('li[data-mth="'+ $(this).data("mth") +'"]');
    if( $group.length > 4 ) $group.addClass("standOut");
  });
}

$(getDates);
```

```css
.standOut{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="date"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put dates in a array where the month is the key, then loop the months and if the count on that month == 5 colour all the dates.

```
 var d;
    var week = 7;       

    $(document).ready(function() {
      getDates();
    });
function getDates() {
      var months = new Array;
      for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        d = new Date();
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + week);     
        var month = d.getMonth();
        if(!months[month]) months[month] = new Array;
        months[month].push(d);    
        week += 7;
      };
      plot_months(months);
    }
    function plot_months(months){
      $.each(months,function(key,month){
               var style = ""; 
             if(month.length > 4) style = "color:red;";          
                 $.each(month,function(week,date){
                   $('#date').append('<li style="'+style+'">' +date+ "</li>");
            });
      });  
    }`
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aupyuny4/2/)